# Remove MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5 without VS installation

Tags: windows-10, mysql, uninstall, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Today I tried to clean up my PC and this includes uninstalling unnecessary stuff. One of the programs is `MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5`. I already uninstalled my Visual Studio installation which was `Visual Studio 2017 Community`. Now every time I try to uninstall/repair the MySQL for VS, I get the error `Visual Studio version 2012, 2013, 2015 or 2017 must be installed.` [This website](https://insidemysql.com/mysql-for-visual-studio-uninstall-workaround/) suggestes that this bug should have been already fixed and it offers some cumbersome workaround.

Since I have no intention on installing VS again, I would be interested in an easy way to remove that program.

Please note that I tried to uninstall via `Control Panel` as well as `CCleaner`. Could some other uninstalling program solve this issue?

---

[image]

Comment: "Could some other uninstalling program solve this issue?" - No, they all work exactly how Control Panel works, so they are all going to have the same problem.  The executable you need to remove it no longer exists on your system.  Have you tried to install just `MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5` by downloading the installation file [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/2.0.html) and then remove it?  You should update your question with any relevant information after doing so.  *I am shocked VS is installing preview software from Oracle.*

Comment: @Ramhound I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. I even get the same error when executing the .msi file. From how I understand it, it is not missing the executable, but something else

Comment: You created the registry values as suggested by your linked article? 2017 would be Visual Studio 15.0

Comment: No, I don't like playing around in the registry. Also I hoped for a way around that

Comment: It would be helpful to know, if the potential solution (provided you adapt it for VS2017), works or doesn't work.  I would rather avoid submitting an answer that doesn't even work.  I suppose the simplest solution, is to write an answer and let the community decide if it's helpful.  You are going to need to decide, between installing VS2017 or attempting registry modification.  *The suggested modification is harmless.*

Comment: I can't submit an answer unless I know which update you have installed for VS2017.  Update your question to include that information.  I also know the full path to `..Common7/IDE/Extensions/Oracle` in order to answer this question

Comment: I tried to adapt the solution from the link, but no success. The message is still the same. @Ramhound what do you mean with `which update you have installed for VS2017`? Like which version?

Comment: There are upwards of 7 updates for VS2017, the current version is 15.7.1, which changes the registry key you require to exist, so I need to which update you had installed.  But I also need to know the path information.  Trying to avoid installing it myself.

Comment: `vs_community__701016564.1520973391` that is the installer executable I used. I would assume one of these numbers is the version. I hope that no other version was installed through updates. The path seems to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now went a simpler way, but not as clean as I wished it to be.

1. Delete the folder containing the files
2. Enter registry editor (regedit) and go the path `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products`
3. Now search for the entry with the right `ProductName`
4. Delete the key (program won't show up in `Control Panel`)
5. Run `CCleaner` to clean the remaining registry entries connected to that program

I think that this is sufficient enough to "uninstall" a program, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.
Install Visual Studio Community from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)
Install Visual Studio for Python(or anything for that matter) and wait until it completely downloads
Now, go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Select MySQL for Visual Studio > Uninstall
Once you're done uninstalling that, you can uninstall Visual Studio also and it's all done!